# Использование предлога.

Tags: предлог

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, верно ли такое написание: "Мы приехали в красивый город. Город музеев". Или же надо так: "Мы приехали в красивый город. В город музеев".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы оформил эту конструкцию не с помощью парцелляции, а с применением приложения: "Мы приехали в красивый город - город музеев".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но вот мне интересен именно вариант с точкой. Вот если говорить о точке, то как будет верно? Вообще возможен ли вариант: "Мы приехали в красивый город. Город музеев"? Или это будет не правильно?

Comment: Вариант с точкой вполне годится, но так любят оформлять свои тексты газетчики (отрывистыми фразами, рублеными предложениями). С точки зрения грамматики, вариант без предлога верный

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если Вас устроил мой ответ, кликните мышкой на знак "принят"

Answer (score 1):

Можно не повторять предлог. Так даже лучше. Тогда это будет назывное предложение. А с предлогом что?

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили. Мне тоже без предлога больше нравится. Но одно - нравится, а другое - как всё-таки правильно. И тогда я стала сомневаться, а правильно ли без предлога? Но раз всё верно, то хорошо.

Comment: Я не знаю, верно ли всё. Я так думаю. Это разговорная речь, тут нет жестких правил.